# Exe Hosted in IIS Calling Generates Http 405 Method not alllowed Error

Tags: http, cgi, iis-7.5, testtrack

I want to use Testtrack SDK API and for that needs to host Test Track SDK server on my server Machine, When I had installed Test Track on my server machine and tried to call it through code it gives me  Error  Http 405 method not allowed.

Is there any specific things which needs to be done in IIS to run exe ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 405 error is a security issue with the IIS web server. You can find step by step instructions for configuring CGIs with IIS in the TestTrack user documentation.
http://help.seapine.com/testtrack/2015.0.1/ttinstall/Default.htm#cshid=WebServerConfigIIS7_8